# ImportError: No module named tpw.tpw_ept.py.api

Tags: class, import, odoo-8

My directory structure is there:
[image]

I am trying to import class of api.py file which is in tpw_ept module.
I am woring on cbf_tpw_ept->py->b2c_sale_order_export.

my code is:

```
from tpw.tpw_ept.py.api import UnicodeDictWriter
```

but it give me error like:

```
 ImportError: No module named tpw.tpw_ept.py.api
```

how can I solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that the directory where `tpw/` resides is added to your `PYTHONPATH` and that it and its subdirectories leading to your module are python packages (contain `__init__.py` file).